# DNS through Cisco VPN

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, vpn, firewall

We have a Cisco ASA providing a VPN gateway for users. Currently when users VPN'n from outside the network they can access file servers from their IP addresses but the shares do not response via share name.

I have checked the DNS settings on the ASA and it is distributing the correct internal DNS server addresses to the VPN client.

I am beginning to think it is something to do with the internal DNS servers not accepting queries from different subnets? Does anyone know this to be a problem? DNS servers are both WinServer2008R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that 53\udp and 53\tcp to your DNS servers are  allowed to the VPN clients by the ASA VPN policy. You should also make sure that the DHCP server for your VPN subnet(s) are giving these DNS servers to the clients.

Comment: Check by doing an `nslookup` of an internal FQDN from an affected client.  If you don't get a response, it's most likely a firewall issue.